# Immidiately remove a button from HTML page when a user chooses to delete it

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am starting to get around Angular JS.

I have a small requirement. I want users to have an option to delete certain buttons, if they wish. And therefore, I want that the button to immediately vanish from the page as soon as the users clicks the close (x) sign.

What is the best way to achieve this?

One technique I thought of is to refresh the page and load the data again. Since I am using routes, I feel just calling the route using ui-sref would do the job. But somehow this doesn't seem to work for me.

Please find the code snippet below.

### Route

```
$stateProvider.state('DefaultSources',{
    url:'/DefaultSources',
    templateUrl:'/static/app/service/template/default_sources.html'
  })
.state('ChannelSources',{
    url:'/ChannelSources/:ch_id',
    templateUrl:'/static/app/service/template/channel_sources.html'
  })
```

### HTML

```
<div id="grid_ch">
  <button class="a" ui-sref='ChannelSources({ch_id: userch})' ng-click='channelSelected(userch)' ng-repeat="userch in userChannels">
    <span class="close" ui-sref='DefaultSources' ng-click='deleteChannel(userch)'>&times;</span>
    <p>{{ userch }}</p> 
  </button>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on the close (x), A functon deleteChannel() is invoked which deletes the data from the DB. I would like to route to DefaultSources after every click because the underlying code for DefaultSources hits the DB and populate the fresh data, which would be much similar to doing a refresh.

However, this technique doesn't seem to work, Since I am a new the AngularJS I cant think of ways to debug.

I would really appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: Why not just flip a flag and hide the button - and then on reload your server code will handle not showing it since it wont exist? No postback, no reload `<button ng-init="canSee=true; ng-if="canSee" class="a" ui-sref='ChannelSources({ch_id: userch})' ng-click='channelSelected(userch); canSee=false;' ng-repeat="userch in userChannels">`

Answer (score 0):

You could eagerly remove userch from the userChannels list when they click delete. This would achieve what you want without having to reload the data at all, but you'd need to have handling in the page if the HTTP request was not successful

The problem if you want it to be a link is that ui-sref won't work on a span or a button because they don't support href tags. Additionally, I don't think that you can have an ng-click and an href on the same element, both of those actions will not be executed.

You'll need to redirect in your controller after the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comment above, add an ng-if to the button:

```
<button class="a" ui-sref='ChannelSources({ch_id: userch})' ng-click='channelSelected(userch)' ng-repeat="userch in userChannels" ng-if="!userch.deleted">
    <span class="close" ui-sref='DefaultSources' ng-click='deleteChannel(userch)'>&times;</span>
    <p>{{ userch }}</p> 
</button>
```

and then in your deleteChannel function, do `userch.deleted = true` so it will remove the button